# Should I turn my skewed data into a normal distributed data before using MinMaxScaler or StandardScaler?

Tags: normalization, normal-distribution, skew, minmax

I have a dataset with a couple skewed variables that with the use of sqrt() function turns them into a normal distribution variable.

I have read somewhere that I should have a normal distributed dataset so I could use MinMaxScaler()...

What's your advice to deal with such skewed variable, should I just use minmax or first turn them into normal distributed variables and then use minmax?

I have used sqrt() to turn a skewed distribution into a normal distributed variable.

After that I used MinMaxScaler(), but I am not sure this is the correct way to do things